# How to detect merged branches that were deleted in remote

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm using Git and I'm trying to sync up my local branches with remote ones. I always keep a "master" and a "develop" branches in both local and remote repositories. When I create a new feature, I create a branch for it and name it like this: feature/my-new-feature-name.

When I finish working on the feature, I commit and push all changes to remote repository (I use Gitlab for my remote repo). Then I merge the feature branch into develop branch and delete the source branch (the feature branch) using GitLab interface. At this point, the feature was merged into develop branch and deleted only in remote repository.

After these steps, I wanna be able to sync my local branch to the state my remote branch is. That is, I wanna have my feature branch merged into develop and deleted from local repo.

To do this, I run the following commands:

```
git checkout develop
git pull
git branch -d feature/my-new-feature-name
```

When I do this, Git shows me this message:

```
error: The branch 'feature/my-new-feature-name' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D feature/my-new-feature-name'.
```

Of course I can just run the command using -D flag, but I wanna understand why Git says the branch is not merged.

I found several questions about this in Stack Overflow, but in all of them people suggest running this command in order to check the merged branches:
`git branch --merged`

When I run this command Git shows me only the develop branch, as if feature/my-new-feature-name was not merged. But in fact feature/my-new-feature-name was merged (in remote repo) and pulled to local one. I can also see my merge commit by running `git log`. Why does Git doesn't detect my feature branch as merged into develop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was to set the squash flag to true when merging. Git only detects the merge if you merge without squash.

Answer (score 0):

Your local branch is lacking one commit when compared to develop, though : the merge commit that was made by your PR `feature-branch > develop`.

Either you just disregard git's hint and go for your `branch -D` as you considered, or you can also (even if just to try it out) now merge develop back into your feature-branch (fast-forward at this point) and `branch -d` won't complain any more.

Comment: Let's say the develop branch has commits which my feature branch doesn't have, but all commits from my feature branch are also in the develop. In this case I would except my feature branch to be considered as merged, don't you?
Anyway, I tried to merge develop branch back into my feature branch as you said, but it's still showing me the same message. And I can see some sense in this, as now the develop branch is 1 commit behind my feature (the merge commit).
About using -D flag, I'm avoiding this, because I'm actually building a script. I don't think it's safe to use -D flag inside a script.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point, namely about the scripting. Something else occurred to me though : what are the pull default settings in your config? Will the execution of your script depend on a specific config? Maybe consider going once more through the steps with a "proper" `fetch` followed by an explicit `merge`, just to rule out any unwanted and silent mecanism to come interfere.

Comment: I've got what I've been missing... When I was merging the branch in remote repo, I was setting squash flag to true. By doing this, Git doesn't detect the branch as merged, as in fact, it creates a new commit.