# GitHub branch always one commit behind master

Tags: git, github

I have a GitHub project with a *master* branch and a *dev* branch, when I merged from dev to master, I see that the merge commit seems to cause the dev branch to be considered **one commit behind** master.

Is this something common with such a workflow? Or did I do something wrong? I tried merging back from master to dev, but it became worse (one commit behind + one commit in front). Also tried a rebase merge from master to dev but dev stayed one commit behind.

What's the solution to this?

Thank you

**EDIT with commit history from dev:**
[image]

And master:
[image]

Comment: Why is dev being one commit behind master a problem? You already know the cause (the merge commit), which isn't relavant to the dev branch.

Comment: @chepner Yes, well, basically the fact that a simple merge from X to Y would cause X to be considered behind Y was a little counterintuitive for me at first to the point that I wondered if I didn't do something wrong. But if it's something usual then... great! :) Thanks

Comment: The real problem is the your dev branch is *tracking* master, rather than some other  branch. If `dev` is supposed to track master, then you should be *pushing* commits from dev to master, rather than merging.

Comment: @chepner I'm not sure I understand what tracking means in the context of GitHub UI? Isn't tracking just about a local branch being linked to a remote branch?

Comment: @chepner Originally all I wanted to do was to merge from time to time from dev to master, and never the contrary. In my case I did it because I was confused by the "one commit behind" but would never do that in other cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Ok, you've proceeded with pull requests, but the overall principle is the same : yes when you merge into master for the first time, your source branch (`develop`) becomes in the process effectively one commit behind, like I described in the first version below. You can be reassured that it's typical in this kind of workflow, and it won't keep you from merging down the line, they're just a fast-forward away.

---

*(Below, first version of the answer, wrongly assuming local merge operations)*

When you're at the point you describe after the first merge, with `master` having one more commit, it's the merge commit, as you correctly guessed.

At this point all you need to do if you want the two branches to be perfectly synchronized (although at this point they're already similar in terms of files) is to `merge` master back into `develop`, it will be a simple fast-forward where `develop` gets the last commit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my post with a screenshot of the commit history of both branches, the issue is that I don't remember exactly what I did since I did some rebase merge that probably doesn't appear in the history? What's weird is that from what I remember I did merge again from master to dev, but it hadn't solved it from what I remember.

Comment: In the end, since this is normal to be one commit behind, then it's alright, but I still would have liked to understand exactly what was going on and why I haven't been able to make them exactly equivalent to GitHub.

Comment: Anecdotically, I remember having answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349058/how-to-detect-merged-branches-that-were-deleted-in-remote/54350401#54350401) somewhat similar question today.

Comment: I just tried to `git checkout dev`, then `git merge master`, but after my push, I now have "This branch is 2 commits ahead, 1 commit behind master."

Comment: While it was just 1 commit behind master before :/

Comment: If you just need your develop branch to be in sync with master, why not just drop it altogether and recreate a develop branch fresh from master? (Assuming there's not a whole teaming pulling from develop of course)

Comment: That would be a good alternative, although I'm surprised there doesn't seem to be any other easy way.